# How to set android:networkSecurityConfig only to single flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We deliver release apk build from a specific `flavor`(`QA`) to our QA team.

I would like to add `networkSecurityConfig` only to that `flavor`.

In order to do that I need to add next config to the manifest.

```
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"... >
        ...
    </application>
```

Is that possible to add such config only to `QA` `gradle flavor`?

*Preventing answers about `<debug-overrides>` it will not help me, since we delivers release build to QA.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure.

Suppose the flavor is `vanilla`. In `app/src/vanilla/AndroidManifest.xml`, have an `<application>` element with your `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute, and nothing else. You can also have the `network_security_config` resource be in that flavor (`app/src/vanilla/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`). Then, `vanilla` builds will merge in that attribute; other builds will not have it.

Comment: It solved my problem. I've forgot that you can have several AndroidManifest for different flavors.